# How to deactivate maps zoom property

Tags: javascript, maps, zooming

I'm having a problem about the zoom property in my map. The deal is: I'm developing a full one page looping and I need to insert the map but, when you get in the section of the map screen and need to scroll up or down, just doesn't happens, because you're moving the zoom instead the page.

My js is:

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-23, -46),
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    var meukml = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url:'http://oceanos.nap.usp.br/remmarsp/tvlhico/contourfgradeSBB01.kmz'
    });
    meukml.setMap(map);        
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I think that is necessary just to deactivate the zoom. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing it in the map options !

```
 var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-23, -46),
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
    'controls': {
        'zoom': false
    },
    'gestures': {
        'zoom': false
    }
}
```